# Javascript Firebase Arrays

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a Firebase project and we are using Vue.js for the framework.

Is there a way to Create, Update, and Delete elements in a Firebase cloud document?

For example, we have a collection called people, and in that collection it has documents and some documents have arrays, as far as I know, Firebase does not support mapping values like Address: 123 Test street, but instead only supports array elements like a string or number.

I have found the arrayRemove methods from the docs but not much more.

Below is a function I am importing that deletes an item well enough, but I guess my main focus is updating one.

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { projectFirestore } from '../firebase/config'
import { doc, updateDoc, arrayRemove } from "firebase/firestore";

const useDocumentArray = (firebaseCollection, id, arrayItem) => {
    let error = ref(null)
    let isPending = ref(false)

    let docRef = doc(projectFirestore, firebaseCollection, id);

    const deleteArrayItem = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await updateDoc(docRef, {
                shifts: arrayRemove(arrayItem),
            });
            isPending.value = false;
            return res;
        } catch (err) {
            isPending.value = false;
            console.log(err.message);
            error.value = 'could not delete doc';
        }
    };

    return { error, isPending, deleteArrayItem };
};

export default useDocumentArray;
```

Comment: Maybe Firebase tutorials already covers your question. It could be `addDoc`, `updateDoc` and `deleteDoc` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to Create, Update, and Delete elements in a Firebase cloud document?

Yes, there is a function for each operation you mentioned. So you can [set](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document) a document, you can [update](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data) or [delete](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data) a document.

> For example we have a collection called people, and in that collection it has documents, and some documents have arrays, as far as I know, Firebase does not support mapping values like Address: 123 Test street, but instead only supports array elements like a string or number.

Firestore supports fields of type string as well as arrays. So please check [supported data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types). Besides that, an array in a Firestore document cannot store only strings and numbers, but any supported data type but not arrays. So if you need more complex elements, please note that you can also store objects.

> I have found the arrayRemove methods from the docs but not much more.

Yes, `arrayRemove` can help you remove a specific element from the array. But there is also an `arrayUnion` present, that can help you [add a new element in the array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

Comment: Hey Maneland. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?